# Yii::app()->createUrl() vs $this->createUrl

Tags: yii

I'm just learning Yii framework and creating URLs in a controller is confusing me. The createUrl() method is in both CApplication and CController but it behaves differently. I can't really figure out, when to use which?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Yii::app()->createUrl() you must provide a contoller/action path.

In the controller method, you don't need specify the controller ID, sou you only pass the action to createUrl.

See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#createUrl-detail and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createUrl-detail

Answer (score 0):

I try to use the `CControler->createUrl();` when I'm in a controller, this includes the views.
When I'm in a component or another globaly used object, I'll use the `Yii::app()->createUrl();`